# Is the space of probability distributions an infinite dimensional space?

Tags: probability, dimension-theory-analysis

Is the space of probability distributions an infinite dimensional space? If so, would you explain how?

This is a follow up question to an answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110235/comprehensive-list-of-distributions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already the probability distributions on $\mathbb N$ are an infinite-dimensional convex set since the Dirac measures at $1$, $2$, ..., $n$ are linearly independent, for every $n$.

Comment: A more interesting question is probably cardinality rather than finite v. infinite. If one restricts it to Dirac measures as done in this answer, I'd think it's countable; but I don't think things would need to be weakened much to become uncountable instead.

Answer (score 2):

The space of probability distributions is not a linear space, so you presumably do not mean linear dimension.

The space $\mathcal P([0,1])$ of probability measures on $[0,1]$, for example, has infinite Hausdorff dimension.  Perhaps that is what you mean.  We use a standard metric on the space $\mathcal P$ for this.  For example:
$$
D(\mu,\nu) = \sup \left|\int f \,d\mu - \int f\,d\nu\right|
$$
where the sup is over all functions $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ bounded by $1$ and Lipschitz constant $\le 1$.